# Ruby File methods seem not to work, causing the script to fail

Tags: ruby, ubuntu

I have a BigBlueButton (video conference) platform installed on an Ubuntu server to record meetings. The process, after the recording is ended, is the following:

- Process recordings
- Publish recordings

A Ruby script is used to process and publish, and is the core of the solution.  I am adding a feature to generate thumbnails from the webcam videos, and adding it into the publishing script.  After the process script is done , the publish script runs and checks to see if a webcam video exists or not.  If so, it copies the video into the publishing directory and uses the new feature to generates the thumbnails.  The problem is that after adding the feature, the publish script fails with a publish.fail error.

Here is the code for the new feature:

```
def GenerateThumbnails(video_dir,x)
  BigBlueButton.logger.info("Making Thumbnails dir")
  thumb_dir = "#{video_dir}/thumbnails"
  FileUtils.mkdir_p thumb_dir

  if x == true
    BigBlueButton.logger.info("Made Thumbnails dir - Generating Thumbnails")

    command="ffmpeg -ss 5 -i #{video_dir}/webcams.webm -vf "select=gt(scene\,0.4)" -frames:v 5 -vsync vfr -vf fps=fps=1/10 #{thumb_dir}/thumb%d.jpg"

    # -ss 5 : To discard the 5 first seconds of the video.
    # -vf "select=gt(scene\,0.4)" : To filter only frames    # that have 40% change or more,compared to previous      # frames.
    # -frames:v 5 : To get 5 frames in total.
    # -vsync vfr : Makes sure that the 5 frames,are different # from each others.
    # -vf fps=fps=1/10 : Generates 1 thumbnail for everty    # 10th span of the video.

    BigBlueButton.execute(command)
    BigBlueButton.logger.info("Generated Thumbnails - Picking the most representative thumbnail")

    # The following code picks the thumbnail with the biggest        # size,since more size means more details.

    i = (1..5).map {|i| File.size("#{thumb_dir}/thumb#{i}.jpg").to_f }.each_with_index.max[1]

    File.rename("#{thumb_dir}/thumb#{i + 1}.jpg", "thumbnail.jpg")

    # We get an array of file sizes from thumb1.jpg up to    # thumb5.jpg
    # Then,we get the index of the greatest value of the     # array.
    # Finally , now that we know that i is the index of the   # greatest value in the array, then thumb#{(i+1)}.jpg is # the file with the greatest size, so that's the one we    # want to replace the name of,with 'thumbnail.jpg' ,which # will be called later in the image source.

    BigBlueButton.logger.info("Picked the most representative thumbnail")
  else
    BigBlueButton.logger.info("Made Thumbnails dir - Copying the standard wrap image to the folder")
    FileUtils.cp("/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/remark/remark/global/photos/views-960x640.jpg","#{thumb_dir}" )
    File.rename("#{thumb_dir}/views-960x640.jpg", "thumbnail.jpg")
  end
end
```

[Here](https://github.com/bigbluebutton/bigbluebutton/blob/master/record-and-playback/presentation/scripts/publish/presentation.rb) is the Ruby code used to publish.

I added my function before the begin, and then called it within the begin, as follows :

- `GenerateThumbnails(video_dir,true)` at line 951
- `GenerateThumbnails(video_dir,false)` at line 953

## Edit:

What i actually get in the log files is the following :

> Permission denied - (/foo/thumbnails/thumb7.jpg, thumbnail.jpg)

I tried to force the permissions, like this:

```
File.chmod(0777, "#{thumb_dir}/thumb#{i + 1}.jpg") rescue nil
File.rename("#{thumb_dir}/thumb#{i + 1}.jpg", "thumbnail.jpg")
```

However, I still get the same error.

I did not write the publish script, and I'm trying to make the new function work properly in the overall publish script.

What can I do to correct the issue?

Comment: Is there a typo in the line `command="ffmpeg -ss 5 -i #{video_dir}/webcams.webm -vf "select=gt(scene\,0.4)" -frames:v 5 -vsync vfr -vf fps=fps=1/10 #{thumb_dir}/thumb%d.jpg"` ? 
If not, then you are closing the string prematurely :)

Comment: What do you mean by typo?

Comment: Also note that a backslash is the escape operator in a ruby string, so you would have to escape the backslash with another backslash `scene\\,0.4`

Comment: I mean is that your actual code, or maybe a mistake in the copy-paste process. If its your original code, then maybe that is the problem.

Comment: Yes it is the original i just checked it.

Comment: Try this `command="ffmpeg -ss 5 -i #{video_dir}/webcams.webm -vf \"select=gt(scene\\,0.4)\" -frames:v 5 -vsync vfr -vf fps=fps=1/10 #{thumb_dir}/thumb%d.jpg"` maybe thats gonna fix it.

EDIT: Wait im gonna write an answer so I can show you what I mean

Comment: Okay,i will try it and come back.

Comment: No that was not the error,is there any other suggestions? i just edited the question you may want to check the edit

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are closing a string prematurely in the line

```
command="ffmpeg -ss 5 -i #{video_dir}/webcams.webm -vf "select=gt(scene\,0.4)" -frames:v 5 -vsync vfr -vf fps=fps=1/10 #{thumb_dir}/thumb%d.jpg"
```

(Note how the code changes color at `select=gt(scene\,0.4)`)

I guess you want to have quotes inside your string, but are unintentionally closing the string instead. Try escaping the quotes like this:

```
command="ffmpeg -ss 5 -i #{video_dir}/webcams.webm -vf \"select=gt(scene\\,0.4)\" -frames:v 5 -vsync vfr -vf fps=fps=1/10 #{thumb_dir}/thumb%d.jpg"
```

Also verify you need the backslash in "gt(scene\,0.4)", looks a little weird to me ;)

Answer (score 1):

The line of code that's failing is this:

```
File.rename("#{thumb_dir}/thumb#{i + 1}.jpg", "thumbnail.jpg")
```

Note that in Linux, a `rename` can also move a file, and that's what is happening here.  I don't believe that the file is intended to be moved, so the line should look like this:

```
File.rename("#{thumb_dir}/thumb#{i + 1}.jpg", "#{thumb_dir}/thumbnail.jpg")
```

However, if you did intend to move the file, you should specify the proper directory (even if it's `thumb_dir`), so that it doesn't just get moved to the current directory, which can easily be changed implicitly.

```
File.rename("#{thumb_dir}/thumb#{i + 1}.jpg", "#{thumb_dir}/thumbnail.jpg")
```

Why is this happening?  Your process user apparently doesn't have permissions to write to the **current** directory, whatever that happens to be.  The call to `File#chmod` is unfortunately a red herring, and will pretty much always succeed as long as the file exists, even if it silently fails and does nothing.  `File#rename`, however, will not silently fail.

If you intend for the file to be moved to the **current** directory, make sure that the process that your app runs in has proper permissions to write to the current directory.  If you continue to receive the `Permission denied` error, insert the following code before the `File#rename` line:

```
listing = `ls -la .`
puts "Directory: #{listing}"
```

This will tell you what the actual file permissions are for the process user for the current directory.  From there, you should be able to take appropriate action.

Comment: The process did actually create that thumb_dir as you can see in the above code,so i am pretty sure it has proper permissions,since creating and renaming need the same permissions . Plus ,the directory is known for me so i do know the permissions and the owner,so,both are 755

Comment: @MrRobot Thanks for your feedback.  I updated the answer accordingly, and I think that will solve your problem.  I kept most of the previous content, but repurposed it slightly based on the new suggestion.  I do hope that it helps.